# How can I put a space between the lines of a line chart using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am currently drawing 4 lines. I would like to have a space between each series of lines. Something like that in the picture.

how can I do it?

http://plnkr.co/edit/qmkxYEJYpIkXUQUMQMDa?p=preview

```
paths.attr('transform', null)
            .transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .ease('linear')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + x(now - (limit - 1) * duration) + ')')
            .each('end', tick)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `translate` to each individual path, just translate them by a different amount of `y` to separate them from each other.

An example can be found at [this fork](http://plnkr.co/edit/jpjoZA?p=preview) of your code.

As you loop through the groups, you are already adding a path for each group.  You can just add another attribute: `.attr('transform', 'translate(0, ' + yTranslate + ')')` and then increment `yTranslate` by a distance of your choice (e.g. `50`) for each group.

If you prefer, you could also make the amount of y-translation a property of the group, and set it up in the group definition earlier.  This would be similar to how you specify the `color`.

Comment: thank you for answer!. but I have 2 problems. if I create a new series, and I put a color for example blue, this new series is not shown. and I do not know why the values are cut at the top.  https://i.imgur.com/tIhXINQ.jpg

Comment: in my real example I need have 14 series for example

Comment: @yavg just adjust the y-domain of your graph so that the lines do not overlap.  I have done this for you as an example here http://plnkr.co/edit/jpjoZA?p=preview and please mark this answer as accepted if it solves your problem.